Using replace token task for the file in the agent and resolving git bash path error
I have ensured git bash installed on the agent but still coming up with following error and i also added env variable
ERROR:
Unable to locate executable file: 'bash'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also verify the file has a valid extension for an executable file.
I want to replace the token from that agent itself since that file will be available in the folder from the agent only, not in source code. and that file being generated from one of the task from azure pipeline.
that file content example:
https://dev-domain.com
here in above url, dev can be stage , prod etc , it need to be parameterized and use the replace token

worked on installing git bash
worked on adding the env variable path
worked on replace token task but it is working if file is available in the source code, not if file is being generated in the agent directly.



Unable to locate executable file: 'bash'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also verify the file has a valid extension for an executable file.

I can reproduce the same issue when using the Windows Self-hosted agent.

Based on your description, you have installed the git bash.
To solve this issue, you can add bash command folder in the PATH of environment variable on the agent machine.
Here are the steps:
Step1: Check if the bash.exe exists in the git bin folder.
For example:

Step2: You need to login the agent machine, and then add C:\Program Files\Git\bin to the Path of Environment Variables, then Restart the agent.

Result:

Update:
To integrate all the steps into the Pipeline, you can add the following tasks:
steps:

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Install Git And Config PATH ENV
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      # Define the URL of the Git installer
      $gitInstallerUrl = "https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.40.1.windows.1/Git-2.40.1-64-bit.exe"
      
      # Define the path to save the installer
      $installerPath = "$env:TEMP\Git-2.40.1-64-bit.exe"
      
      # Download the Git installer
      Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $gitInstallerUrl -OutFile $installerPath
      
      # Run the installer silently
      Start-Process -FilePath $installerPath -ArgumentList "/SILENT", "/NORESTART" -Wait
      
      # Optionally, remove the installer after installation
      Remove-Item -Path $installerPath
      $env:Path = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","Machine") + ";" + [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","User")
      echo $env:Path
      $gitpath = git --exec-path
      $bashpath = $gitpath.Replace('mingw64/libexec/git-core','bin')
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PATH]$bashpath;$(PATH)"


- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo "test"
      

Update2:
To directly update the file on agent machine, you can use the Bash task to run the sed command to achieve it.
Here is an example:
variables:
  newvalue: dev01

steps:
- bash: 'sed -i -e "s/dev02/$(newvalue)/g" filename'
  workingDirectory: 'Local Path folder where the file located(e.g. C:\Users\xx\Downloads)'
  displayName: 'Bash Script'


,Thank you, it seems to be worked as i have not seen that error after using above PS script, and on the other hand as i mentioned in the description, can you also please suggest on usage replace token in the file from agent machine , and that file will be available in the folder from agent not in the source code. and for example that file consist of URL  https://dev02.domain.com/  so I should have option to parameterize dev02 or dev01 or dev03 etc ,   I have used replace token task to do when file is in source code, and it is successful but I am not sure when file is only in agent only

@user25518631 The Replace token task can not directly meet your requirement. To directly update the file on agent machine, you can use the Bash task to run the sed command to replace the variable. Refer to the update2 in the answer.
